# Toggle click on a mapped data React JS

Tags: reactjs, toggle

Here is my main component in which I render a component based on the data I receive from API:

```
  <div className="PlayersContainer">
          {players.map((player) => {
            return (
              <PlayerPhoto
                key={player._id}
                {...player}
                selected={selected}
                something={(e) => {
                  setSelected(!selected);
                 }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
```

and here is inside my  component:
export default function PlayerPhoto({ name, img, something, selected }) {

```
  return (
    <article
      className={selected ? styles.Fade : styles.PlayerBox}
      onClick={something}
    >
      <img src={img} alt={name} className={styles.PlayerPhoto} />
      <p className={styles.PlayerName}>{name}</p>
    </article>
  );
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that when the user clicks on a player it shoud take the fade class and become fade, and when the user clicked again it should returns to its normal class.

the problem is when the user clicks on a player all players get the fade class and become selected. How can I get their id and add the fade class to that specific player id?

Comment: why don't you store the id of the player on click and in the selected option check if current player id and the selected one match if so then it fades other it won't

Comment: I want but I dont know how since I am a totally newbie

Comment: have  a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71110558/17497509 @Shan answer that's what I was saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not move this logic to `PlayerPhoto`?

```
export default function PlayerPhoto({ name, img }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <article
      className={selected ? styles.Fade : styles.PlayerBox}
      onClick={()=>setSelected((prevValue)=>!prevValue}
    >
      <img src={img} alt={name} className={styles.PlayerPhoto} />
      <p className={styles.PlayerName}>{name}</p>
    </article>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a state to maintain the selected id and then compare the `selectedId` and player id for the `selected` prop boolean value. if the id matches , it will change the className.

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

<div className="PlayersContainer">
  {players.map((player) => {
    return (
      <PlayerPhoto
        key={player._id}
        {...player}
        selected={player._id === selectedId}
        something={() => setSelected(player._id)}
      />
    );
  })}
</div>;
```